# Windows 10 Window (with buttons and images)

Tags: window

I feel like this is such a simple question, but I haven't been able to find info on it anywhere.

I'm looking to make a Windows 10 window with buttons that can lead to other pages/links, and pictures, but I cannot find any way to even get a blank window!!
If anyone could help me, that would be great;)

If you need more info on what I'm trying to do, leave it in the comments and I'll try to answer so you can help me more.

Thanks!!

KingNoahCraft5

Comment: which language are you building this in?

Comment: i was going to do it in c++, but any other language could work